# Ubuntu what free tools packages available for making professional software mockups?

Tags: gnome, package-management, python, gimp, gnash

Like: http://www.balsamiq.com/  for Linux is there any professional quick mockup builders available? (not pen and paper we know we do that mostly but it needs to be quick and professional for sharing, not like open-office power point or gimp or with wine macromedia flash).

Something specially dedicated for linux in a sense of making specific professional mockup's under linux. is there somthing?

Comment: [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) might be what you're looking for. Haven't used it myself but it looks promising. Others might be able to give some more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) is built for the purpose of providing a free and open-source GUI prototyping tool that people can easily install and use to create mockups in popular desktop platforms.

<sup>Source:[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn)</sup>